# No wired network connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I'm struggling to get a wired connection out of my Ubuntu workstation. I'm running 20.04 and the ethernet ports aren't picking up a connection from our outlets (no flashing lights, just "Cable Unplugged" in the network settings). I don't think it's hardware as if I connect an ethernet cable from that machine to my Mac or my other Ubuntu workstation it establishes a connection. If I connect a USB-ethernet dongle it picks up a connection as well. I've tried different outlets and different cables with no change. When booting from a live-USB (22.04) it can't pick up a connection either so I am hesitant to reinstall (I've never had a Ubuntu installation experience that didn't get me stuck in GRUB for days). I've been through many similar questions here on fiddling with things in /etc/network, interfaces, ifup, etc., to no avail.

I'm an absolute networking novice and pretty new to Ubuntu in general - usually plugging a wire in is as technical as I ever need to be! I work at a US university and the IT staff have not been very helpful, having no experience with Ubuntu. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: And see how/if your system detects the hardware with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`.

Comment: Using jouralctl I saw `ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist`, and I see 4 similar readouts (4 ports on the back); `device (ens82f0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')`, but both of these messages are also displayed by my other working machine that is able to connect to the network. I tried the other command and can't see anything suspicious like a error with networks. I'm inclined to think the hardware is detected if the machine picks up a network connection when connected via ethernet cable to another Ubuntu/Mac.